# Can connect to my program through localhost, but cannot connect using other computers on network

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote a program to play tick tack toe across a network (or potentially the internet). I wrote this using C.

The program works just fine when I run the host and client on the same machine. I cannot, however, establish a connection when it is running on two different machines.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on both computers. I don't see why this would matter, but one is connected to the router via ethernet. The other is connected to the network wirelessly. ufw verbose shows that the firewall is inactive on both computers.

Things that I've already tried:

1. Adding server name to the host in /ect/hosts instead of typing
   the ip address into the program argument (works both ways on local
   machine, does not work either way across the network).
2. Adding firewall exception to the router firewall.
3. Port forwarding the port that I'm using (5001) on my router.
4. nmap to the ip of the computer running the host shows that port 5001/tcp is open with service "commplex-link"
5. Can telnet into the host from remote computer across the network.

```
void network_host(void) {

    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    struct game *main_game = createboard();

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("On opening socket ERROR: \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof serv_addr );
    portno = 5001;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr ) < 0 ) {
        perror("On socket binding ERROR: \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Waiting for opponent . . .\n");
    listen(sockfd, 1);
    clilen = sizeof cli_addr;
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, clilen);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen); 

    if (newsockfd < 0) {
        perror("On accepting connection ERROR: \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Opponent connected!\n");

    while (main_game->play) {
            printboard(main_game);
            entermove(main_game, GAME_HOST, newsockfd);
            checkwin(main_game);
    }
}

void network_client(char *host_name) {

    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    struct game *main_game = createboard();

    portno = 5001;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("Error opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server = gethostbyname(host_name);

    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, no such host.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof serv_addr);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error connecting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (main_game->play) {
        printboard(main_game);
        entermove(main_game, GAME_CLIENT, sockfd);
        checkwin(main_game);
    }
}
```

Since this program will work when connected to localhost, nmap shows the port open remotely, and I can telnet into the program remotely, I can't at all figure out where to go next.

It would seem to me that its not a coding error since it works locally, but since I can telnet into the program then it seems that it should't be a networking error.

I'm willing to backtrack through these steps (maybe some of them I've only done half right). But also willing to accept other possible ideas.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   how do you expect us to reproduce the problem?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: what host name are you using when trying to access another computer across the network?

Comment: OT:  always check the returned value from calls to C library functions, like: `socket()`, `accept()`, `listen()`, etc to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is where your problem is

```
memcpy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
```

`memcpy` is defined as taking a destination, source and size...so you're copying things the wrong way around as `server` is where the address is. Swap things around and it should work just fine...

```
memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);
```

You don't need to cast anything either as firstly those two arguments to `memcpy` are meant to be `void *` not `char *` and secondly, pointers convert to `void *` automatically

Comment: A better solution is to replace `gethostbyname()` with [`getaddrinfo()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) and let it allocate and populate proper `sockaddr` structs for you.

Comment: @Chris,

Thank you so much. I'm so sorry that I had to get someone to correct my code. This is a real lesson that even if something appears to be working, it may not be. I'll definitely be more careful with my code next time.

Also, thanks for the added tip about typecasting. I got a bit "cast happy" there, and I can definitely see how that can potentially hide some errors and cause problems down the line. I'm still new and learning mostly on my own (except for kind people like you).

Comment: @Remy

Thanks for the tip, and the link. I'll read up and learn that function before I use it though, but its great to get that kind of input because its verging on overwhelming to be trying to get a grasp on all these functions on my own. I didn't even know of its existence.

One thing to note, however, is that I seem to be using a possibly outdated practice. Should I be assuming that getaddrinfo() (and by extension gethostbyname()) should be returning a list of addresses.

I just noticed that netdb.h says

"#define h_addr h_addr_list[0] /* for backward compatibility */"

Comment: @NicholasR yes, `gethostbyname()` and `getaddrinfo()` both return a list of addresses. You should try to connect to each address until one succeeds. A hostname can have multiple IPs, and you might not have a network route to all of them, so try them all. `gethostbyname()` is deprecated in favor of `getaddrinfo()`, as the latter supports both IPv4 and IPv6, is reentrant, etc

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Remy.

You've been immensely helpful. Like I said, its quite difficult learning these nuances on your own. I'll have to learn to do a better job at looking at documentation, but I suspect this is a skill that will take quite some time to develop.